# How to intercept Menu shortcut event in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

On a Firemonkey Form add a main menu and a single submenu item. Set the shortcut property for the submenu to Ctrl-A.

Is there anyway to intercept the Ctrl-A before it gets to the menu? It seems that the form OnKeyDown doesn't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form checks if there are child components that want to handle the key. If the key is handled then that is the end of the story.

Here's a quick&dirty way that prevents the `TMenuItem` from handling the key, using an interposer.

```
type
  TMenuItem = class(FMX.Menus.TMenuItem)
  protected
    procedure DialogKey(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
  end;


procedure TMenuItem.DialogKey(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (ssCtrl in Shift) and (Key = 65){A} then exit;       
  inherited;
end;
```

If you are using actions then you have to override the `DialogKey` function of the `TActionList` in the same way.

Comment: Wouldn't it be also posible to intercept this key combination using forms OnKeyDown event while having KeyPreview property enabled on that form?

Comment: @SilverWarior, you're talking about VCL, this question is for the Firemonkey framework. In FMX there is no KeyPreview because all keys are already captured by the form. If a child component handles the key then the forms `OnKeyDown` will never fire.

Comment: I didn't knew that. I thought it is same as for VCL. I gues we learn something new every day.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, one thing I've noticed however is that if you have a second form it will not see shortcut keystrokes associated with the main form. This means for example if you have a tmemo on a second form and the main form uses the Ctrl-v short cut in the main menu, it's not possible to paste text into the memo using Ctrl-v. This is unique to FMX, VCL works as expected where a second form receives all key strokes irrespective of shortcuts on a main form.

Comment: Your solution works. I'm now going to post another question that will ask how to pass these intercepted keystrokes on to the currently active form.