# How to pass keystrokes onto a second active form in Firemonkey

Tags: firemonkey

I encountered some behavior in FMX that is different in VCL. This relates to how main menu shortcuts are processed. It seems that an FMX application will intercept all shortcut keystrokes in the main form such that any other active forms do not see these keystrokes.

This means for example if you have a TMemo on a second form and the main form uses the Ctrl-V main menu short cut, it's not possible to paste text into the memo using Ctrl-V. This is unique to FMX, VCL works as expected where a second form receives all keystrokes irrespective of shortcuts on a main form.

An answer in this question [How to intercept Menu shortcut event in Firemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924994/how-to-intercept-menu-shortcut-event-in-firemonkey) explains how to intercept shortcuts in the main form.

The question here is how to get these intercepted keystrokes from the main form to the currently active form, so that controls such as TMemo or TEdit on the second form work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer in [How to intercept Menu shortcut event in Firemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924994/how-to-intercept-menu-shortcut-event-in-firemonkey), one way to pass on the mainmenu shortcut keystrokes, eg Ctrl-A, to the currently active form is to use this code in the main form:

```
TMenuItem = class(FMX.Menus.TMenuItem)
protected
  procedure DialogKey(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
end;


procedure TMenuItem.DialogKey(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
var ch : char;
begin
  if (ssCtrl in Shift) and (Key = 65){A} then
     begin
     ch := #0;
     Screen.ActiveForm.KeyDown(Key, ch, Shift);
     exit;
     end;
  inherited;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer to the first one, it's works but not everyone might like it, plus it has limitations. For simple cases is should work.

Before showing the second form, remove the shortcuts from the mainform, then restore the shortcuts when the form returns control to the mainform. Works ok if the second form is shown using showmodal. Pity there isn't a form OnShortCut event as we have in VCL. Eg rough example:

```
(MainMenu.Items[0] as TMenuItem).Items[0].ShortCut := TextToShortCut('');
FormTwo.ShowModal;
(MainMenu.Items[0] as TMenuItem).Items[0].ShortCut := TextToShortCut('Ctrl+V');
```

Comment: I actually decided to do this, as I only need it for Ctrl+C and it works like a charm.  I use the main form's `OnActivate` and `OnDeactivate` events.  PS. using VCL c++ ( I just realized this wasn't a VCL question, sorry)